# Problema con Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Buenas que tal? tengo un problema, instale el codigo de seguimiento que me dio Analytics en una web lo puse en el head de la misma, ahora el problema pasa que no me muestra las distintas paginas me muestra el trafico pero siempre me aparece en la misma pagina, el sitio tiene una parte estatica que es el menu una barra lateral y cada pagina se carga dinamicamente en el medio de eso, nose si me explique me parece que por ahi puede venir el problema alguien tiene alguna idea? gracias

Answer (score 0):

bienvenidx. No sabemos con certeza cómo se cargan las cosas dinámicamente. Por lo que ve GA, pareciera que es un iframe o algo similar. Si pudieras mostrar algo de código para ver cómo cargas cada página, podría haber respuestas más útiles.

Por ahora, leeremos el tarot de StackOverflow y adivinaremos: si lo que cargas dinámicamente son páginas en el mismo dominio, podrías poner el tracking code en todas las páginas dinámicas (usa un footer común o algo, así no tienes que escribir lo mismo 276726 veces). GA usa first-party cookies, que son específicas al dominio de la página que las carga. Si el marco y las dinámicas son del mismo dominio, saldrá todo en los reportes de la misma cuenta; si son sub dominios distintos, será más aburrido y hay que leer [la documentación](http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55524).

Hay info *legacy* sobre cómo hacer tracking en iframes [aquí](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#trackingIFrames), pero no sé si hay un equivalente para versiones más recientes del script de GA.

Comment: la pagina en cuestión es http://www.anbeg.com.mx/ no la cree yo a la web y la etiqueta la pego la desarrolladora pero tengo contacto si es q hay q hacer alguna modificación